# Show sent emails in my inbox on iPad

Tags: ipad, email, gmail, mobile-mail

Is there a way to make my sent emails show up in my inbox on the iPad, similar to how it is shown in the gmail web view?  I can do this in the Mac app by creating a smart mailbox that includes both inbox and sent messages. Is there something I can set up, either on the iPad or in gmail, that would let me do this?

Comment: Why can't you just add yourself as a recipient?

Comment: I cc myself, but for some reason I only see the message in the SENT message folder, but not the INBOX. This seems quirky. Does anyone else have this type of behavior in Apple Mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always simply view the "Gmail/All Mail" folder.

Inside Mail on your iPad, go to Mailboxes-> Gmail (under accounts) -> All Mail.

You'll see messages you've sent as well.  If Gmail is your only mail account, simply stay in the All Mail folder all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings>Mail, Contacts, Calendars and turn on "Always BCC Myself". Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you send the message, send it CC: to your own mail address to receive a copy into your inbox.